# .htaccess rules resulting in 404 error for /page/ if /page.[ext] is present

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The problem: the presence of an identical URL to /page/, but with some file extension, i.e., /page.xml, results in a 404 for /page/.

So for example, my HTML sitemap, example.com/sitemap will 404 if example.com/sitemap.xml is present.

The .htaccess file of my Wordpress site contains rewrite conditionals that, as expected, appends a trailing slash to pages in the form of example.com/page so they are rewritten as example.com/page/.

**.htaccess as follows:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN MainWP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/mainwp-child/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/THIS_PLUGIN_DOES_NOT_EXIST [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END MainWP
```

Comment: Disable `MultiViews`?

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging, I found the solution, which was to simply disable Multiviews in my .htaccess file, like so:

```
Options -MultiViews
```